# java.nio.channels.OverlappingFileLockException in a QT application on Android

Tags: android, qt

My QT app crashes with `java.nio.channels.OverlappingFileLockException` exception on `Nokia 1` device with the following call stack:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: [dbp] processing com.google.android.gms.vision.service.operation.DownloadDependencyOperation for action com.google.android.gms.vision.service.DOWNLOAD
Process: com.google.android.gms, PID: 1740
java.nio.channels.OverlappingFileLockException
    at sun.nio.ch.SharedFileLockTable.checkList(FileLockTable.java:255)
    at sun.nio.ch.SharedFileLockTable.add(FileLockTable.java:152)
    at sun.nio.ch.FileChannelImpl.lock(FileChannelImpl.java:1080)
    at java.nio.channels.FileChannel.lock(FileChannel.java:1053)
    at oyb.a(:com.google.android.gms@12685020@12.6.85 (040304-197041431):12)
    at oyb.a(:com.google.android.gms@12685020@12.6.85 (040304-197041431):1)
    at com.google.android.gms.vision.service.operation.DownloadDependencyOperation.onHandleIntent(:com.google.android.gms@12685020@12.6.85 (040304-197041431):3)
    at com.google.android.chimera.IntentOperation.onHandleIntent(:com.google.android.gms@12685020@12.6.85 (040304-197041431):2)
    at dbn.a(:com.google.android.gms@12685020@12.6.85 (040304-197041431):8)
    at nam.a(:com.google.android.gms@12685020@12.6.85 (040304-197041431):9)
    at dbs.run(:com.google.android.gms@12685020@12.6.85 (040304-197041431):10)
    at dbp.run(:com.google.android.gms@12685020@12.6.85 (040304-197041431):9)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1162)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:636)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
```

what can it be?

The device parameters are:

[image]

QT version: 5.14.2

Comment: is this solved??

Comment: @Lokesh no, I have no idea how to solve this

Comment: I see the same error with a native app, same device.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe this is too late for an answer and you already fixed the problem but I actually had the same issue with the same test device. I just contacted the Google Play Support and after resubmitting my app, as they told me to do, it was quickly released in the Play Store (they probably manually accepted it after contacting them). Hope this helps although you have probably already found a solution!