# Fatal Exception in com.google.android.gms.vision.service.DOWNLOAD

Tags: android, google-play-console

So this is probably a very specific issue but after I finished my app that is relying on the Mobile-Vision-SDK I uploaded it to the Play Console and released it to the review. Apparently there was an error on a Nokia Nokia 1 (Android SDK 27 / Android 8.1) phone resulting in rejection of the app. All other test devices had no errors (the app is designed to run on minSDKVersion 19 and is targeted to SDK Version 29).

This is the error log:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: [dbp] processing com.google.android.gms.vision.service.operation.DownloadDependencyOperation for action com.google.android.gms.vision.service.DOWNLOAD
Process: com.google.android.gms, PID: 1793
java.nio.channels.OverlappingFileLockException
    at sun.nio.ch.SharedFileLockTable.checkList(FileLockTable.java:255)
    at sun.nio.ch.SharedFileLockTable.add(FileLockTable.java:152)
    at sun.nio.ch.FileChannelImpl.lock(FileChannelImpl.java:1080)
    at java.nio.channels.FileChannel.lock(FileChannel.java:1053)
    at oyb.a(:com.google.android.gms@12685020@12.6.85 (040304-197041431):12)
    at oyb.a(:com.google.android.gms@12685020@12.6.85 (040304-197041431):1)
    at com.google.android.gms.vision.service.operation.DownloadDependencyOperation.onHandleIntent(:com.google.android.gms@12685020@12.6.85 (040304-197041431):62)
    at com.google.android.chimera.IntentOperation.onHandleIntent(:com.google.android.gms@12685020@12.6.85 (040304-197041431):2)
    at dbn.a(:com.google.android.gms@12685020@12.6.85 (040304-197041431):8)
    at nam.a(:com.google.android.gms@12685020@12.6.85 (040304-197041431):9)
    at dbs.run(:com.google.android.gms@12685020@12.6.85 (040304-197041431):10)
    at dbp.run(:com.google.android.gms@12685020@12.6.85 (040304-197041431):9)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1162)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:636)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
```

At the moment I don't have an idea for fixing this neither found a solution for this.
I'm not certain but this Github issue tab (https://github.com/googlesamples/android-vision/issues/350) might reference the same error but does not include a fix for it. Maybe someone here has a solution or an idea to fix this. Thanks in advance for any answers!

Comment: Just found another thread reporting issues with the same device: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61201428/java-nio-channels-overlappingfilelockexception-in-a-qt-application-on-android

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After contacting the Google Play Support and resubmitting it the app is finally up in the Play Store. They probably accepted it manually after I contacted them.